# Class Graphing in DocBlox on Windows is not Working

Tags: php, graphviz, docblox

I can not get the class graph to generate on Windows, and I am not sure where to look for an error. I installed Graphviz as an Administrator on Windows 7, and everything seems to be appear to be working.

I used the DocBlox.xml file that works on a Ubuntu computer and generates the graphics, but I do not get anything on Windows.

Any thoughts on what could be wrong, or where to look for errors?

Command Line in the main directory:  docblox --force -v

docblox.xml -> [DocBlox.xml](http://www.ontariodarts.com/docblox.xml) 
doxblox.log -> [DocBlox.log](http://www.ontariodarts.com/docblox.log)

When I go to the project, the graphic is a simple graphical X in IE 8, for missing image.
Classes.svg is 2K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this happens because DocBlox is unable to find the `dot` executable that is installed with GraphViz. This is easily tested by going to an arbitrary directory in your Command Prompt and typing `dot`.

If this does not work then you need to add the GraphViz binary folder to your path.

Should this not be the solution; please paste your output when using the `-v` (verbose) option so that DocBlox will output additional information.

**Update**
It appears I either misread the opening post or the subsequent edits: there is nothing wrong with your DocBlox installation. IE8 and below do not natively support SVG; in order for this to work you would need to either upgrade your browser or install the (now discontinued) Adobe SVG Plugin.

Comment: Running dot did not give an error.  It simply paused, so it looks to be in the path.  dot -v returns 'dot - graphviz version 2.28.0 (20110507.0327)

Comment: I attached the logs via a website of mine, as I am not sure how to simply attach files here.

Comment: Were you able to get the logs?  Sharing the folder to Ubuntu Linux 11.10, and running the docblox --force, has allowed the graphics to be generated, so I can get the image without Windows.

Comment: They are linked in the main message. Here->[link](http://www.ontariodarts.com/docblox.xml) and Here->[link](http://www.ontariodarts.com/docblox.log)

Comment: Good catch, the image file is actually drawn (418K), so it is just the IE display issue.  Thanks.